# How to resize buttons automatically if the window changes its size?

Tags: qt

I have a window and a bunch of push buttons. This window will be my "Main Menu". After placing the buttons, I would like to have these buttons fixed to the size of this window. So they should fill the window and change their size if the window changes its (by the user for instance).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use layouts. According to the documentation,

> The Qt layout system provides a simple and powerful way of
>   automatically arranging child widgets within a widget to ensure that
>   they make good use of the available space.

Example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:

};
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
    QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");

    //Horizontal layout with two buttons
    QHBoxLayout *hblayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    hblayout->addWidget(button1);
    hblayout->addWidget(button2);

    QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
    QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");

    //Vertical layout with two buttons
    QVBoxLayout *vblayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    vblayout->addWidget(button3);
    vblayout->addWidget(button4);

    //We add our two layouts (horizontal & vertical) to the
    //following vertical layout.
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(hblayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(vblayout);

    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
```